# Price regex commas thousands

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to come up with a regex which will match a price and cover all bases. The main issue is the (potential) comma and decimal place.

```
/^[^\d]*(?<price>\d+,?\d+\.\d+)/
```

is the best one I've come up with so far but it doesn't match £3.00 because the two `\d+ \d+` either side of the optional, I need to make the left `\d+`optional.

(preg_match php)

I already explained how it was different before you marked it as a duplicated. And what is the point of marking it as duplicate after it has been answered. .

Comment: dozen dupes on this site

Comment: it's nothing like that question it's very specific how to change the match number to optional.

Comment: Don't just assert that it isn't a duplicate - edit the question to explain *precisely how* the other answers fail to address your specific question.

Comment: Don't just assert it is a duplicate. Trying reading both questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the

```
\d+
```

to a

```
\d*
```

The `+` means one or more occurrences. The `*` means zero or more; or in other-words optional.

Answer (score 0):

A money regexp with pattern group `(?<price>(\d+((\.|\,)\d+)+))`

Source:

```
<?php

$input_line = "
£3.00
£30.00
€34.020,00
£35,000
£12,345,6789.100
";

preg_match_all("/(?<price>(\d+((\.|\,)\d+)+))/", $input_line, $matches);

var_dump($matches['price']);
```

Result:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "3.00"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "30.00"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "34.020,00"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "35,000"
  [4]=>
  string(15) "12,345,6789.100"
}
```

Explaination for `/(?<price>(\d+((\.|\,)\d+)+))/`:

- `(?<price>(\d+((\.|\,)\d+)+))` Named capturing group price
- 2nd Capturing group `(\d+((\.|\,)\d+)+)`
- `\d+` match a digit `[0-9]` with + for matching between one and unlimited times
- 3rd Capturing group `((\.|\,)\d+)+` again with +
- 4th Capturing group  `(\.|\,)`

  - 1st Alternative: . matches the character . literally
  - 2nd Alternative: \, matches the character , literally